# Python tkinter: Make any output appear in a text box on GUI not in the shell

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a GUI using python and tkinter and just wondering if there is anyway to make any output text appear in a window on the GUI not on the interpreter/shell?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python : Converting CLI to GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351786/python-converting-cli-to-gui)

Comment: not really a dup is it

Comment: are you asking how to do "print 'foo'" in your GUI, but have it magically appear in the text widget?

Answer (score 8):

If, as suggested in Bryan Oakley's comment, you want to “print 'foo' in your GUI, but have it magically appear in the text widget”, see answers in previous question [Python : Converting CLI to GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351786).   This answer addresses the simpler issue of how to produce output in a text box.  To produce a scrolling text window, create and place or pack a text widget (let's call it `mtb`), then use commands like `mtb.insert(Tkinter.END, ms)` to add string `ms` into text box `mtb`, and like `mtb.see(Tkinter.END)` to make the box scroll.  (See “[The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)” documentation for more details.)  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as tk

def cbc(id, tex):
    return lambda : callback(id, tex)

def callback(id, tex):
    s = 'At {} f is {}\n'.format(id, id**id/0.987)
    tex.insert(tk.END, s)
    tex.see(tk.END)             # Scroll if necessary

top = tk.Tk()
tex = tk.Text(master=top)
tex.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
bop = tk.Frame()
bop.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
for k in range(1,10):
    tv = 'Say {}'.format(k)
    b = tk.Button(bop, text=tv, command=cbc(k, tex))
    b.pack()

tk.Button(bop, text='Exit', command=top.destroy).pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Note, if you expect the text window to stay open for long periods and/or accumulate gigabytes of text, perhaps keep track of how much data is in the text box, and use the `delete` method at intervals to limit it.

Comment: what I need is a box that is placed on the GUI window that displays any text that is output from functions called by buttons placed on the gui