# Redirecting IDLE output to a GUI (Python33)

Tags: python, redirect, tkinter, output, python-idle

Is there a way to redirect all IDLE output to a tkinter GUI, or do something with the IDLE outputs? I want to show all IDLE output from the `http.server` module in a tkinter GUI, to monitor all things happening to a webserver. Is this doable with a few simple functions/commands or will this involve editing the IDLE lib files?

Asked something similair before, I wanted to embed the whole IDLE/python shell in my monitoring program, but this seems impossible with the newest python version.

EDIT:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys, time, threading
global TXT
root = Tk()
TXT = Text(root, font="Arial")
TXT.pack(fill=X)

class RedirectText(object):

    def __init__(self, TXT):
        self.out = TXT

    def write(self, string):
        TXT.insert(END, string)
sys.stdout = RedirectText(TXT)

for i in range(10):
    print("test", i+1)

def thread():
    print("Delayed")
    threading.Timer(1, thread).start()

threading.Timer(1, thread).start()
root.mainloop()
```

**Removed all faulty code, now have this. Will not write anything system related, just what is inside a `print()` function. Still looking for a way to `insert` all system output into a text widget.**

Comment: See [this answer][1] for a Tkinter example of redirecting stdout to a text widget.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12352237/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley Once again, a wonderful answer! Exactly what I needed. Somehow didn't find it and I did a lot of googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12352237/7432) for an example of redirecting stdout to a Tkinter text widget.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to redirect IDLE output, you want to redirect the system standard output. Here's a little something I've used before for WXPython:

```
class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self, TextCtrl):
        self.out = TextCtrl

    def write(self, string):
        wx.CallAfter(self.out.WriteText, string)
```

And then to initialize:

```
 import sys
 sys.stdout = RedirectText(log)
```

Where log is a WX TextCtrl widget.

Comment: looks pretty clear, but unfortunately wxPython is not available for python 3.3. I think it's doable though with tkinter. Is `TextCtrl` a widget? And `CallAfter`'s use seems pretty vague to me. But basically what I interpret is that you make a text widget, and redirect the system standard output to that widget?

Comment: I imagine that Tkinter has a similar system that you can use. When you print something in your Python script, the print function calls sys.stdout.write, so if you overwrite that with a new object that also has a write function, it'll result in a redirected print statement.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12352237/7432) has a Tkinter example of redirecting stdout to a tkinter text widget