# Console output to tkinter text widget

Tags: python, user-interface, redirect, tkinter, output

I have created a GUI for my selenium web automation tool.

Now the only thing I can not figure out is how I could get my console output shown in a text widget in my tkinter GUi.

Is there a way I could redirect all console output?

I am very new to python and programming at all.

Comment: You need to redirect stdout: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/06/16/python-101-redirecting-stdout/

Comment: Looked into it. But can't find a solution to carry over to tkinter text widget.

Comment: Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351786/how-to-redirect-print-statements-to-tkinter-text-widget?rq=1 Answer from user Yuukio (Method1)