# Python, tkinter - Momentanously open a cmd or similar and print "live" output to it; then close it

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cmd, gurobi

I have the following problem/doubt. Maybe there is already an answer to this question in the forum, but I am struggling to find it because I don't know how to define my question with not many words in google.

I am developing an application with a GUI using `tkinter` (I will later pack it with `pyinstaller`) and using `GUROBI` (which is an optimization software).

Lets say that, after pressing a `button` I will execute a `function` (the function uses gurobi's functions). When gurobi's functions are used, they `print` data in my `console` about the `process`.

The thing is:

1. when I press the `button`, I want to open a `cmd` window or similar and `print` everything there, until the function finishes. Then close it. It must use my current `venv`.
2. If the user wants, I have to give him the chance of `stopping` the process and retrieve the latest solution found. In **PyCharm**, when I run a script I usually have this red button to stop it (image1); but when running a `gurobi` process, I have to press it TWO times instead of one to kill all the processes (if I only press once, ONLY the `gurobi` process stops and gets the latest solution, and then my script continues normally after finishing my created function - THIS IS WHAT I WANT, but in the newly created `cmd` window or similar).

To clarify, I provide this MRE. I cannot show how the functionality (2) works because you would need a `Gurobi` license to reproduce the code, so I have just described that functionality. Also, I provide an image (image2) that shows the "things" `gurobi` prints in the console

Image1

[image: Image 1 - the red button]

Image2

[image: Image 2 - example of printing]

MRE: (without gurobi)

```
from tkinter import  Tk, Button, Toplevel, Label
# import gurobipy as grb

def example():  # THIS is the function that needs to get its output in the CMD and be broken if requested, NOT PARENT
    # gurobipy stuff would go here
    for i in range(int(1.5e6)):
        print(i)

    return 'GUROBI SOLUTION'


def parent():
    gurobisol = example()
    b = Toplevel(root)
    b.geometry('250x250')
    b.configure(background='green')
    c = Label(b, text=gurobisol)
    c.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
    b.mainloop()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x250')
button = Button(root, text='Click me', command=parent)
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance

I searched about this in google and SO, but mostly found people just trying to run python in cmd. Found some people talking about `os.popen()` and `subprocess`, but I don't know what they exactly are and whether they are what I need or not.

Comment: Good question with a great mre. Does `gurobi` use another thread/process to print the stuff on the screen or is it all from the main thread? Have you thought about overriding `sys.stdout.write`?

Comment: Thanks @TheLizzard. About the `sys.stdout.write`, I never heard about that (I am an industrial engineer, so my programming knowledge is self-taught). I've searched it now but it don't get what you are suggesting.

Comment: Secondly, about the gurobi thread/process: I am not sure about that. Considering that gurobi is a paid software, they don't easily provide access to their code as doing so would make easier to reverse-engineer them, so I am struggling to find it. Anyways, I am trying to find it

Comment: `sys.stdout.write` is a function that accepts a `str`ing and writes to the the standard output (the terminal). `print` statements actually call `sys.stdout.write` so if you override it, all print statement inputs will be redirected to your function which can add it to `tkinter.Text`. If `Gurobi` uses writes to the terminal from python, it will be easy to capture its output. For example look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12352237/11106801).

Comment: The example might be useful. However, there might still be 2 problems
1) The "stopping button" would still not be present - I would try to add a button that triggers "KeyboardInterrupt"
2) Using a Text widget means using a GUI - I wanted to call a separate console just because GUIs gets frozen when one of their buttons triggers a heavy function (so they become unresponsive because it is still on the same thread) - I will try to use threading to solve it.

Comment: Why run in a separate process/window? You can implement everything you describe - including stopping, capturing output, and more via Gurobi callback functions.

Comment: @GregGlockner, please could you be more specific please? which `callback` functions are  you referring to? Would it be possible to have an MRE?

Comment: See [callback.py](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/examples/cb_py.html), which is also available in the examples/python subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I've looked at gurobi's docs but it seems that it isn't a solution for my problem, as the printing is still done in the current console and not in other new, so I will go with @TheLizzard 's approach

Comment: You're welcome to code however you want, but one point of a Message callback is that it lets you capture the output and let you put it anywhere you want - another window, a progress bar, etc. This was part of the design.

Comment: @GregGlockner Looking again at the callbacks, I think we are both partially correct. Using the msg callback or overriding sys.stdout.write might serve for the same goal but we still have the need of using threading to print this messages on the separate window (in both cases), where we can also add a button that terminates the model when the user clicks it (instead of pre-defining rules as for example reaching an X% gap). I find this situation fairly interesting so I write this comment to support both points of view.

Comment: Done. I will post tomorrow or the following day an answer with an MRE using gurobi's callback + threading to print the results in an extra window (threading prevents it from freezing)

Answer (score 2):

As Greg already mentioned in the comments, you should use [Gurobi Callbacks](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/cb_codes.html) for your application. This will allow you to stop the current optimization, check on the progress (primal and dual bounds), and also provide access to all log lines that normally end up in the terminal and/or the log file.

You can check out an example of many different callbacks in this example: [callback.py](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/examples/cb_py.html)